# How does length variable works internally on arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Being a variable, how length can return the size of an array in a way that it's computing the size somehow internally?

Comment: Does the duplicate post answer your question?

Comment: Yes, It did. Thank you for marking. Sorry for a delayed response.